# Use value from 2d array as worksheet name

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I declared a 2d array by:

```
WS_array_bodem = [{"Gewasbescherming" ,"range_gewas"; "Bodem-Bemesting","range_bodem"; "Biodiversiteit", "range_biodi"; "Water", "range_water";"Energie","range_energ"}]
```

Then I would like to use the values from the first column of this 2d array as names of worksheets like below. I first had these array's defined as 1d, and then it worked, but adding the extra demension for some reason makes the code fail, displaying:

> Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Using `msgbox(WS_array_bodem(1,1)` I get the string: Gewasbescherming. So what goes wrong in the code below?

```
Dim lastrow_gewas As Integer
    lastrow_gewas = WB_score.Worksheets(WS_array_bodem(1, 1)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Dim range_gewas As Range
    Set range_gewas = WB_score.Worksheets(WS_array_bodem(1, 1)).Range("B1:B" & lastrow_gewas)
```

WB_score is defined as:

```
Dim WB_score As Workbook
    If BookOpen(scorebook) Then
    Else
        Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & scorebook)
    End If
    Set WB_score = Application.Workbooks(scorebook)
```

And works fine.

The worksheet I'm trying to reference is present in WB_score.

Comment: What error are you getting. Do you have a worksheet with that name in the `WB_Score` workbook?

Comment: @JNevill thanks for pointing that out, edited it in.

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting, if you hard-code that worksheet name into that same line that is erroring, does the error go away? (Just want to make sure we are pinpointing the array as the right culprit. Also, is your array declared and, if so, what type?

Comment: It is declared as a variant. Hardcoding the name into it still makes it error out, so it probably isn't the array then...

Comment: mmmm seems something strange is going on. I closed the scores workbook, and reopened it, and the error message is gone. Both in a line with hardcoded sheet name, as in a line using the array for a sheetname.

Comment: That is peculiar for sure. I'm curious if the issue is just in referring to the workbook itself and possibly the way that variable is set. Can you add a breakpoint on the line that is erroring (select anywhere on the line and hit F9). Then check the locals window and insure that the `WB_Score` is set to the workbook that contains that worksheet name.

Comment: It points to the right folder and file.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 possible errors. Try like this to avoid them:

```
Dim lastrow_gewas   As Long
Dim wks             As Worksheet

Set wks = wb_score.Worksheets(WS_array_bodem(1, 1))

With wks
    lastrow_gewas = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Possible errors:

- usage of Integer for the rows;
- you are not referencing the correct worksheet for .Rows
- You are not having worksheet "Gewasbescherming", but it is written in another way. In this case you will get an error in `Set wks` line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vityata. Using Long instead of Integer should make no difference, and I checked it doesnt. As I commented above, restarting the WB_score resolved the problem.

Comment: @Luuklag - You are welcome. Concerning `Long`, Put some 40.000 lines in column `B` and check again for the no difference thing.